# JUnit Test throwing ClassNotFoundExcpetion while execution

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, appium

I'm trying to write a simple Appium test for android app using Junit in Eclipse. The below is my code.

```
@Test
    public void test() throws MalformedURLException{
        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;        
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "C:\\Automation\\ExpediaHotelsFlightsCarsv6.10.0.apk");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.APPIUM);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.ANDROID);
        ***driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);***
        driver.launchApp();
    }
```

I'm getting the below error while running the test at the line

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function   at
>   AppiumTest.test(AppiumTest.java:37)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.common.base.Function   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 26 more

Please help me fix this and understand the solution.

Thanks,
KK

Comment: Format your question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure you have added all dependency for selenium in your pom or build path. You must have below jar in your pom,

```
selenium-server-standalone-XXX.jar
selenium-java-XXX.jar.
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. I missed the selenium-server-standalone-xxx.jar in build path.